# Standard error of mean vs. standard error of coefficient in Gaussian glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, standard-error

I'm having trouble understanding why calculating the standard error of the mean: 
$$
\widehat{SE} = \frac{\widehat{SD}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
gives me a different SE estimate than the SE estimate of a coefficient from a Gaussian GLM (identity link function) in R. Can someone explain why the maximum-likelihood estimators of the standard error of the model coefficients are different from the simple formula for the standard error of the mean?

Here's the code I'm using to play around with this:

```
set.seed(55)
  # make up normally-distributed data
x    <- c(rep('Treatment1', 20), rep('Treatment2', 20))
y    <- c(rnorm(n=20, mean=5, sd=5), rnorm(n=20, mean=8, sd=5))
dat1 <- data.frame(X=x, Y=y)
dat1
  # calculate summary stats
library(psych)
sum1 <- describeBy(x=dat1, group=dat1$X)

  # run glm with normally-distributed residuals
m1 <- glm(y~x, family='gaussian', data=dat1)
summary(m1)

  # create summary table
table1 <- data.frame(ID=c('Mean', 'Coefficient', 'SE', 'Coefficient_SE', 
                          'Upper 95% CI     (mean)', 'Upper 95% CI (Coefficient)', 
                          'Lower 95% CI (Mean)', 'Lower 95% CI (Coefficient)'),
                     Treatment1=c(  # mean
                                  sum1$Treatment1$mean[2], 
                                    # coefficient
                                  m1$coefficients[1],     
                                    # SE
                                  sum1$Treatment1$se[2],  
                                    # Coefficient SE
                                  summary(m1)$coefficients[1,2], 
                                    # Upper 95% CI (mean)
                                  sum1$Treatment1$mean[2] + 1.96*sum1$Treatment1$se[2], 
                                    # Upper 95% CI (coefficient)
                                  m1$coefficients[1] +1.96*summary(m1)$coefficients[1,2],
                                    # Lower 95% CI (mean)
                                  sum1$Treatment1$mean[2] - 1.96*sum1$Treatment1$se[2],
                                    # Lower 95% CI (coefficient)
                                  m1$coefficients[1]-1.96*summary(m1)$coefficients[1,2]),
                     Treatment2=c(  # mean
                                  sum1$Treatment2$mean[2],
                                    # coefficient
                                  m1$coefficients[2] + m1$coefficients[1], 
                                    # SE
                                  sum1$Treatment2$se[2],  
                                    # Coefficient SE
                                  summary(m1)$coefficients[2,2], 
                                     # Upper 95% CI (mean)
                                  sum1$Treatment2$mean[2] + 1.96*sum1$Treatment2$se[2], 
                                    # Upper 95% CI (coefficient)
                                  m1$coefficients[2] + m1$coefficients[1] + 
                                           1.96*summary(m1)$coefficients[2,2],  
                                    # Lower 95% CI (mean)
                                  sum1$Treatment2$mean[2] - 
                                       1.96*sum1$Treatment2$se[2], 
                                    # Lower 95% CI (coefficient)
                                  m1$coefficients[2] + m1$coefficients[1] - 
                                       1.96*summary(m1)$coefficients[2,2])
                     )
```

Comment: @filups21 similarly to stackoverflow, questions like this are welcome on cross validated, especially if (i) you do some research for existing answers (which you have), and (ii) put some effort into the question (which you have).

Comment: Try the model $y\sim 1$ . It should give the standard error you mention. Is your question, then, why the standard error for the constant `y~1` differs from that of the slope in `y~x`?